# How do I do custom approximate string matching in C#?

Tags: c#

My input is stored in the variable `source` and I compare with variable `targetString`. So, I want that it gets the result like in the column `result`:

```
    source          targetString                    result
-------------------------------------------------------------

    Canada          Canada - Fan Club                 true

    Real Madrid     Real Madrid(Football Club)        true

    Chelsea         FC - Chelsea                      false

    Wolfsburg       FC Wolfsburg                      false
```

I tried [with `FuzzyString` in CodePlex](https://fuzzystring.codeplex.com/). But in the columns that have the values `Chelsea` and `Wolfsburg` it also returns `true` in the comparison modes `Weak`, `Normal` and `Strong`.

Is there any method to resolve my problem that is simpler than using `FuzzyString`?

Comment: Isn't this better suited for Excel or Acces-like products?  Not sure if this is an incidental problem you have to deal with or if it's a requirement for some system.

Comment: What are the rules you want to follow? I an;t even see why first example gets `true` and the third one is `false`

Comment: So you only care if the `String` starts with the value? Why not use [`String.StartsWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx) then?

Comment: It does not seem fuzzy nor approximate at all. From the table you provided it all looks like a prefix search. Try `StartsWith`  on a string.

Comment: I don't know `StartsWith` after reading all comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From going on your current example, it appears that you only want strings to return true if they start with the value specified. So, what you can do instead is use [`String.StartsWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx) method like so:

```
public boolean checkString(String source, String targetString) {
    StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.InvariantCulture;
    return targetString.StartsWith(source, comparison);
}
```

[For different types of `StringComparison`, check the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx)

If your rules change, please let me know and I can update the answer.

Comment: Your answer exactly I want to find.